# Listbox items to data file c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm tring to create a .dat file which contains all listbox items.

this is the writing code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Test.dat", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
         listBox1.Items.Add("Hello");
         listBox1.Items.Add("World");

         string[] words = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
         listBox1.Items.CopyTo(words, 0);

         foreach(string word in words)
         {
             w.Write(word);
         }

         w.Close();

         fs.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is the reading code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {

        textBox1.Text = r.ReadString();

        r.Close();

        fs.Close();  
    }
}
```

But I only get the first item **Hello** from the listbox.
Is there a way to get all the items from the listbox and make them a string data file ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx      You're not moving to the "next" line.  You should create a method that returns a List<MyObject> .. where MyObject would have your 2 properties.  Don't mix "datalayer" code and UI code.  Datalayer is "code that read some datastore (even a text file)..........UI is where the textboxes are.  You're mixing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it much more complicated:

To save the items:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"Test.data", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

And then to read them back, reverse the process:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"Test.data"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I guess sometimes a short code it way better then a long one.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a foreach, why don't you use

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    w.Write(listBox1[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference plus `listBox1` is (probably) a `ListBox`, not an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Tried this one too but didn't work nither. for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        w.Write(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                    }

Answer (score 0):

To read from a BinaryReader, **if** that is what you need, you need a loop like this:

```
while (r.PeekChar() >= 0) textBox1.Text += r.ReadString() + "\r\n";
```

or else you get only the first string.

Peek checks to see if more is in the reader without advancing the file pointer, see here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.binaryreader.peekchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Of course to create a text file form the Listbox's items' texts LarsTech's answer is the way..